# What is the correct way to use the foreach command in a Tikz loop?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to define nodes in a path. I have come up with the following TikZ code which fails to compile:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    [
   hlc/.style={circle,inner sep=5,draw}
]
 \def\odl{0,...,7};
 \path foreach \x in \odl { node[hlc] (\x) at (\x,\x) {\x}; }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Could some one point out to me what is wrong with my code.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Every spin of the loop should produce a valid path specification. But because you have the semicolon inside the loop, after first spin, it is basically trying to make sense what `\x` might be and thinks that you are trying to execute some non-TikZ code and trips. Effectively it is trying to do this

```
\path node[hlc] (0) at (0,0) {0} ; % Done with path but not with the loop
      node[hlc] (1) at (1,1) {1} ; 
      node[hlc] (2) at (2,2) {2} ;
```

While effectively this shouldn't cause an error, it does when it is inside the loop. The path ends after the loop is finished hence the semicolon belongs outside the braces

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    [
   hlc/.style={circle,inner sep=5,draw}
]
 \def\odl{0,...,7}
 \path foreach \x in \odl { node[hlc] (\x) at (\x,\x) {\x} };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Is the `;` after the `\def` line even necessary? (I know the OP also had it)

Comment: Thanks a lot @percusse. I did not know that that the `;` after the `\def` command would make such a big difference. Your contribution has been to be very helpful. Cheers!

Comment: @daleif My mistake I forgot

Comment: @user24098 That's my mistake. I'm talking about the `;` inside the loop not after `\def`. That's unnecessary